# I want to hover on a button and change another class but it doesnt work

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to hover on a button and change another class but it doesn't work, I tried multiple ways and I just cant seem to figure it out. Below is the HTML and CSS for the code.

Essentially, I'm trying to make it so when I hover over a button the circle will slowly go up to a specific amount of pixels so I decided to do a background-color test but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(
  () => {

    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var xp = 0;
    var yp = 0;
    $(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
      $(".cursor").css("left", event.pageX - 25);
      $(".cursor").css("top", event.pageY - 25);
      $(".cursor").css("display", "block");
    });
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.cursor {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none
}

.buttonTest:hover~.cursor {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 1em;">
  <button class="buttonTest">Test Button</button>
</div>
<div class="cursor"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: `~` selector is for [siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) - your `.cursor` is not a sibling of `.buttonTest`.  It works if you either add the class .buttonTest to the button div wrapper, or remove the wrapper: https://jsfiddle.net/mupt1gnz/

Comment: @freedomn-m so how can I make it when it is not for siblings?

Comment: As per [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) MDN page:  *here are no selectors or combinators to select parent items, siblings of parents, or children of parent siblings.* - so you simply can't say:  buttonTest's parent's sibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wee bit of javascript can facilitate this. Using JQ's `hover()`, you can specify both hoverOn and hoverOff fns.

```js
$(document).ready(
  () => {
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var xp = 0;
    var yp = 0;
    $('.buttonTest').hover(
      () => $('.cursor').addClass('changeColor'),
      () => $('.cursor').removeClass('changeColor'))
    $(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
      $(".cursor").css("left", event.pageX - 25);
      $(".cursor").css("top", event.pageY - 25);
      $(".cursor").css("display", "block");
    });
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.cursor {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: background-color 2s;
}

.changeColor {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 1em;">
  <button class="buttonTest">Test Button</button>
</div>
<div class="cursor"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `div` with the `.cursor` class must *not* be empty.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What must go in it? Can it just be e.g. a `&nbsp;`? Can you [edit] your answer to include an example of what _would_ work?